# POST <target url> 419 (unknown status) - can't post data in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a DOM event where the user clicking a table row's header (`th`) cell will delete the corresponding row from the database that supplies the table's data.

This code worked as intended framework-less, by just POST'ing an AJAX containing the row's id info from index.php to delete.php which then ran a sql query.

However, after moving the site to Laravel I ran into an error:

```
POST http://sandbox.app/delete 419 (unknown status)
```

The JavaScript piece responsible for attaching the delete event and posting the id through AJAX:

```
    function attachDelete() {
        $("#mainTable tbody tr th").on("click", function(e){
            console.log(e.target.innerText + " was clicked");
            var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            var id_to_delete = e.target.innerText;
            $.ajax({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'text',
                url: 'delete',
                data: { 
                    'id_to_delete': id_to_delete,
                    "_method": 'POST',
                    "_token": token 
                },
                success: function () {alert("Deleted!"); },
                failure: function() {alert("Error!");}
            });
        });
    }
    attachDelete();
```

The `console.log(e.target.innerText + " was clicked");` goes off.

However, the `success` / `error` messages do not appear.

Going to http://sandbox.app/delete directly brings up a Laravel error window with lots of text, and this part highlighted:

```
 protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
    {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
    }
```

I've added the token variables after reading answers to related questions on StackOverflow. This didn't help.

In case it matters, the route:

```
Route::post('/delete', 'TasksController@delete');
```

The controller :

```
class TaskController extends Controller
{
    public function delete() 
    {
        include 'config.php';

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM food WHERE id = :id');
        $stmt->execute(['id' => $_POST['id_to_delete']]);
    }

}
```

The code inside delete() used to just be the contents of a delete.php file in the old, framework-less site, where everything worked.

I've tried doing it without the controller by creating a delete.php view (with the same code as the delete() function).  It didn't make a difference though:

```
Route::post('/delete', function () {
    return view('delete');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems if you are communicating with POST at the backend. So, you should be configuring your routes on the **api.php** instead of **web.php**

Place your route associated with controller

```
Route::post('/delete', 'TasksController@delete');
```

Inside api.php file.